# Randomly choosing a letter in textbox to be upper or lower cased

Tags: vb.net

How can I set it up so a sentence in a textbox would be randomly (for each letter) be upper or lower cased, for example:

"Hello I am Greg" will go into to "hEllO i aM gREg"

Something like that, thanks.

Comment: go to MSDN and read up on `Random` and `String.Replace` and also [ask]

Comment: Show us what you have tried and where your stuck before just asking for help...

Comment: Each char in a `mYsTrINg` variable can be accessed using an index `i` like `MyString(i)`. You can create a String like this : `MyString = New String(MyArrayOfChar)`. MSDN, .ToUpper(), etc. Have a try then ask specific questions. It doesn't make sense to try to become a programmer if you don't even try to elaborate (on) the logic that would bring the result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: explanations will be given as comments

```
    Dim input As String = TextBox2.Text '<--- this should be input "Hello I am Greg" 
    TextBox2.Text = "" '<--- clear the textbox to store output
    Dim rnd As New Random '<---- generating new random number 
    For Each c As Char In input '<--- iterate through each character
        If rnd.Next() Mod 2 = 0 Then
            TextBox2.Text &= UCase(c) '<--- if true then print particular letter in upperCase
        Else
            TextBox2.Text &= LCase(c) '<--- if true then print particular letter in LowerCase
        End If
    Next
```